# What is C#'s equivalent to Haskell's newtype?

Tags: c#, haskell, newtype

In Haskell, there's two ways of providing an alias for types: `type` and `newtype`. `type` provides a *type synonym*, which means the synonym is regarded by the type checker as exactly the same as the original type:

```
type UserId = Int
hasAccess :: UserId -> Bool
hasAccess id = {-- stuff --}

-- Elsewhere in the program
login :: Int -> Bool
login n = hasAccess n -- Typechecker won't complain
```

A `newtype` is similar, but is regarded by the type checker as a different type:

```
newtype UserId = UserId Int
hasAccess :: UserId -> Bool
hasAccess (UserId id) = {-- stuff --}

-- Elsewhere in the program
login :: Int -> Bool
login n = hasAccess n -- Typechecker will complain, n isn't a UserId !
```

In C#, you can define type synonyms with a top-level `using` declaration:

```
using UserId = Int;
```

However, a strongly-typed, compiler-checked type alias does not seem to be present in C# by default. I've looked into automatic code generation with T4 templates and CodeDOM to generate a class wrapper, but I don't really know how I could cleanly integrate those into my programming flow.

Ideally, I would like to be able to say on a top-level:

```
// Something like this?
using Int.UserId;

/* Elsewhere */
var id = new UserId(5);

public bool HasAccess( UserId id )
{
    /* Stuff */
}
```

This kicks the code generation into gear *at compile-time*. If that's not possible or provides a chicken-and-egg issue for IntelliSense, an automatic compilation option that runs every *x* minutes (or a button or whatever) would be nice.

Comment: Can you provide some background on why you want to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to compile your code every x minutes?

Comment: What's the use of hiding a type under another type name ?

Comment: @Franck a possible reason could be to save Ariane5 rockets...

Comment: I cannot help but point to F# - while there is no `newtype` in F# you can use single-case discriminated unions (like `type UserId = UserId of int`) and you get the real deal with type-synonyms too (in C# you have to fully qualify them, cannot use generics and have to redo them at the beginning of every file) - **disclaimer**: sadly F#s DUs are not compiled into structs but classes though - so there *is* a performance hit - but usually that does not matter to much in .net land anyway ;)

Comment: @Georg - in .net we all use "by-the-book" TDD and of course we compile&run all tests every minute or so ;)

Comment: @Franck and @Jeroen Vannevel : It makes the types clearer: compare a delegate with type `Func<Int,Int,Double>` and a delegate with type `Func<UserId,DeviceID,DeviceLeasingTime>`. Which one will help you grok the code faster? It's also nice that you can refactor the code to change the internal representation if desired or add extra checks such as that as UserId can only be a natural number.

Comment: @BeerendLauwers i would rather pass a class or struct and it's reusable and don't have to set in every single files.

Comment: @Franck: I think the consensus pretty much is that newtypes are equivalent to structs with a single field.

Comment: https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/ provides a helper for that

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, C# does not have such a feature. The closest you can get to this are structs.

```
public struct UserId
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public UserId(int id) : this() { Id = id; }
}
```

This way, the compiler indeed treats `UserId` and `int` as different types. Furthermore, you can add more methods to `UserId` that make sense given the fact that your `int` is effectively a user id. Note as well that this does not have any effect on the runtime, using a struct with a single `int` field does not cause any overhead against using `int` directly.

*Edit:* Because you asked about T4, if you are working with Visual Studio, you can easily create a new T4 Text template that will expand to (C#)-code and will be compiled automatically. The template will be executed everytime you save it.

Comment: An important thing about newtypes in Haskell are that they are a very cheap abstraction (in fact they are optimised away completely after type checking). In this sense, too, structs are the correct answer.

Comment: So how do you do `deriving Eq` with this?

Comment: @unhammer you don't. You have to implement operators manually (you can delegate to the inner value's operators tho)

Comment: I found out :( And what's worse, some operators are implicitly defined. E.g. if you don't explicitly define `ToString`, one is defined for you (whereas in Haskell the compiler would tell you if anything tried using it as a string without defining/deriving an instance) – this lead to a bug in my C# where now the name of the struct was used as string instead of the contents.

Comment: Next step would be to figure out ho to use it with Entity Framework :-)

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Georg's answer, C# 10 has [record structs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10#record-structs) which allows you to have:

```
public readonly record struct UserId(int Id);
```

Just a reminder that it's still possible to accidentally construct a `UserId` with the implicit parameterless constructor:

```
var uId = new UserId(); // Oops, forgot to pass the argument!
```

That's why you might want to catch the error at runtime by throwing:

```
public readonly record struct UserId(int Id)
{
    public UserId() : this(0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Parameterless constructor should not be used");
    }
}
```

Even this won't prevent all mistakes because parameterless constructor is ignored [in some cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/parameterless-struct-constructors).